# Javascript callback called twice

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, callback

I'm pretty new with coding, and this is really stumping me...

Here is my index.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script>
    fetch('https://www.paulschlatter.com/slideshow/slideshows.txt')
      .then((response) => response.text().then(yourCallback));

    let cache = {}

    function yourCallback(retrievedText, callback) {
      if (cache[retrievedText]) {
        console.log('oops')
      } else {
        let array = []

        console.log(callback)

        array = retrievedText.split(/\n|\r/g)

        let httpsArray = []

        let keysArray = []

        let mappedArray = array.map(item => {
          if (item.substring(0, 5) === 'https') {
            httpsArray.push(item)
          } else if (item.substring(0, 3) === '202') {
            keysArray.push(item)
          }
        })

        const object = { ...keysArray
        }

        for (const prop in object) {
          window['value' + prop] = []
          httpsArray.filter(item => item.includes(object[prop])).map(item => {
            window['value' + prop].push(item)
          })
        }

        const owlImages = document.querySelector('.owl-carousel'),
          owlDiv = document.createElement('img');

        owlDiv.setAttribute('src', window.value0.pop())
        owlDiv.setAttribute('alt', '')

        owlImages.appendChild(owlDiv)
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am not using npm or anything, just straight JavaScript, and HTML.

The function `yourCallback` is firing twice, so even when I ***only*** `console.log` hello world it returns hello world twice to my browser.

Obviously this is not ideal, and I believe that the problem lies in the

```js
fetch('https://www.paulschlatter.com/slideshow/slideshows.txt')
.then((response) => response.text().ten(yourCallback));
```

Comment: not that it will make a difference, but you should chain the promises, `.then((response) => response.text()).then(yourCallback);` - not the position of the `)` - but that's not going to help - as a point of interest, if you `console.log('hello world')` before the `fetch` does that get logged twice?

Comment: also ... .then callbacks get exactly ONE argument, so `callback` in `function yourCallback(retrievedText, callback)` will always be undefined - again, this isn't your issue, just letting you know

Comment: If that fetch() is performed inside an event handler it might indicate the event listener is being added twice. Beyond that nothing shown would cause it to occur twice

Comment: @charlietfl - if you look at the code, the fetch is performed inline :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I get it, that's why doesn't make sense it would fire twice

Comment: This was just a weird bug I guess, because I returned to it after the weekend and it works as expected, thanks everyone for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake, in my app.js file I had the same fetch and yourCallback function, so it was firing twice cause I called it twice :)